# omitting last comma when printing a list

Tags: c, list, csv, formatting

I want to show  prime numbers between two numbers like this 2,5,7,11
but it shows like this 2,5,7,11, there is an extra ",".

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int n1,n2,f,i,j;

   scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);

   for(i=n1; i<n2; ++i)
   {
      f=0;
      for(j=2; j<=i/2; ++j)
      {
         if(i%j==0)
         {
            f=1;
            break;
         }
      }
      if(f==0)
        if(i!=1)
         printf("%d,",i);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Build a string, once done, remove the last character and then print it.

Comment: A common mechanism is to add the comma *before* adding an item, except for the first item.

Comment: `j<=i/2` -> `j <= i / j` and your accountants are happy due to the drastically reduced CPU requirement.

Comment: Just exchange the line `printf("%d,",i);` with `printf("%s%d",(2==i) ? "" : ",", i);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question but not accounting for the point raised by @Bathsheeba:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int n1,n2,f,i,j;

   scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);

   int itemCount = 0;  // NEW

   for(i=n1; i<n2; ++i)
   {
      f=0;
      for(j=2; j<=i/2; ++j)
      {
         if(i%j==0)
         {
            f=1;
            break;
         }
      }

      if (f == 0  &&  i != 1)  // TESTS COMBINED
      {
        if (itemCount++ > 0) putchar(',');  // HERE
        printf("%d",i);                     // COMMA REMOVED
      }
   }
   printf("\n"); // newline at the end
   return 0;
}
```

The only way to really remove a comma after you've added it is if you're building a buffer at runtime - which is a reasonable approach - so here we have to only generate a comma when we need it, before all but the first item.

Comment: can you pls write it without putchar?

Comment: I think you can replace the `putchar` with `printf` yourself?

Comment: @alex What's wrong with `putchar()`? Outputting a single character is exactly what it's for.